# Developing Azure .Net 4.0 Applications

Tags: .net-4.0, azure, visual-studio-2010

Presently .Net 4.0 is not supported on Azure.

This thread indicates that you will not be able to use .Net 4.0 with VS 2010 until it is supported in the cloud.
[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/f9fd7247-0893-447e-bb5a-494bc9543e8a)

I'd like a way to start developing Azure applications locally utilizing the new features of .Net 4.0.  I am fine with not being able to deploy these applications until Azure officially supports it.

From within the VS IDE; I tried replacing .Net 3.5 application references with newer .Net 4.0 references and Visual Studio crashes.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 3):

An update to this old thread. .Net 4.0 has been supported since Azure SDK 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Some features from .NET 4.0 can be added to your application through other means. For example, the recently-released [Reactive Extensions for .NET 3.5 SP1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) includes a [back ported release of Parallel Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2009/11/19/9925951.aspx). And the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/34058#) contains the `Lazy` class and `Tuple` struct. As long as you set "Copy Local" to `true` on any libraries that you add, your application should run (and deploy) successfully.

Obviously, these aren't all the features that are new in .NET 4.0, and not all of them will can be ported back to .NET 3.5 like these can.